# wpf : how to show a data set in a grid view?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datagrid, dataset

i'm moving from windows form to wpf but now i have a problem.

i get info from database(sql server) and store that in a dataset and i want to show that in a datagrid (dg)

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("mysqlconnection");
SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter();
sc.Open();
sd.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table_1", sc);
sd.Fill(ds);
dg.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;//here is the problem
sc.Close();
```

in windows forms it was `dg.DataSrouce` but i can't find that in wpf, any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either add `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` to your `DataGrid` definition or change

```
dg.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

to

```
dg.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

**Update**
Try to add `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`

```
<DataGrid Name="dg" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          ...>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i can see that there are 4 rows which is true but i don't see any columns or data inside those 4 rows !!

Comment: @From.ME.to.YOU: Updated my answer, try to set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` in your `DataGrid` definition